# Getting events from component rendered with RenderComponentAsync

Tags: asp.net, razor, blazor

At the moment i am building a ASP.NET app with blazor woven in. I can render my blazor components with the `Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyComponent>()` function included.

The problem is, is that i want to be able to get event from this components so i can react to them outside of the component itself.

Usually in blazor you would add this to your child component code section like this,

```
    [Parameter] public Action<string> addPressed {get; set;}
```

and then handle it in the parent component like so

```
<MyComponent addPressed="DoSomethingOnPressed"/>
```

How would i got about that when my component was instead instantiated through RenderComponentAsync like this

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyComponent>())
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to react to event on the server-side ? or inside the browser?

Comment: @codevision preferably on the server side as i will be rerendering components

Comment: I don't know if this works, but you can pass parameters to the component, have you tried something like `@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyComponent>( addPressed = DoSomethingOnPressed))`

Answer (score 1):

Just use overload which allow you to pass Model object which will be mapped to Properties of the Blazor application.

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyComponent>(new { addPressed = (_) => Console.WriteLine(_) }))
```

Actual method may be constructed in _Host.cshtml page, or injected via services.

Thanks [Mister Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658697/mister-magoo) for the hint.